# Is there a way to select automatically the row pointed by an FK on a given table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, query-optimization

Today while writing one of the many queries that every developer in my company write every day I stumbled upon a question.

The DBMS we are using is Sql Server 2008

Say for example I write a query like this in the usual PERSON - DEPARTMENT db example

```
select * from person where id = '01'
```

And this query returns one row:

```
id    name    fk_department
01    Joe     dp_01
```

The question is: is there a way (maybe using an addon) to make sql server write and execute a select like this

```
select * from department where id = 'dp_01'
```

only by for example clicking with the mouse on the cell containing the fk value (dp_01 in the example query)? Or by right click and selecting something like ("Go to pointed value")?

I hope I didn't wrote something stupid or impossible by definition

Comment: I am assuming you mean `person` and not `department` in the second query.

Comment: Well, probably you need to make a `new feature request` to `Microsoft`. I guess so.

Comment: @Rahul . . . This is not a desirable feature.  SQL Server already offers several ways to implement that functionality that the OP is looking for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I am bit confused with your comment. Which particular feature? If I have understood correctly, OP want to fetch a set of record from person -> say it returns person_id 10 -> he then want's to click on returned id and get matched record from dept automatically. Which particular feature in MSSQL exactly simulates this behavior ... help me understand? I know there are other way like `view` (what you have suggested) or by `stored proc` but those are kind a manual and not exactly what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Rahul . . . The OP wants to compare a value in the table based on the name in another table.  This is what views were designed for.  Computed columns are another method of achieving this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, not disagreeing you but how do you want to interpret this line in OP's post `for example clicking with the mouse on the cell containing the fk value (dp_01 in the example query)? Or by right click and selecting something like ("Go to pointed value")?`

Comment: @Rahul To be honest, I was actually expecting you to be joking about asking MS for said feature. Anyway, what frankieta asks is a GUI feature, not a SQL feature. I'm guesssing from the 'user story' that what (s)he wants is a way to click on the result-grid and have *VISUAL STUDIO* launch a new query that would fetch the related record from the FK'd table. Probably not impossible, but it would require quite some overhead which frankly is more something for a reporting-system than for a development environment. All IMHO off course.

Comment: Yes @deroby, that's exactly what I was talking about. Just a shotcut, a GUI feature, something to save me from writing the same queries over and over again (or write joins). Yes, I guess it would surely require some kind of overhead, and I guess too that if there was a strong request for such a feature MS would have implemented it already. 
Thanks for the helpful comments GordonLinoff and Rahul

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but that seems like a silly thing to do.  Why would you want to confuse an id with a department name?

Instead, you could arrange things so you could do:

```
select p.*
from person p
where department = 'dp_01';
```

You would do this by adding a computed column `department` that references a scalar function that looks up the value in the department table.  You can read about computed columns [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

However, a computed column would have bad performance characteristics.  In particular, it would basically require a full table scan on the `person` table, even if that is not appropriate.

Another solution is to create a view, `v_person` that has the additional columns you want.  Then you would do:

```
select p.*
from v_person p
where department = 'dp_01';
```

Comment: Yes, a view would be a solution just like a join if all I want is to know about the department, I was just searching for a faster way to do  a select given a FK (the id of the department in my case). 

Since all my foreign keys are phyiscal ones Sql Server should now what table to search for.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you write yourself by saying

```
select * from department where id = 
(select fk_department from person where id = '01')
```

Comment: Yes, it's what I do all day on various tables, I was just searching for a faster way to accomplish it, like an hyperlink which runs automatically a select when clicked on.
I guess Microsoft doesn't have such a feature as you pointed out in your comment

Comment: @frankieta, Yes that's true. No such feature present AS OF NOW.

Comment: @frankieta, if you want to do it in a single step; consider having a stored procedure.